# Python : text replacemnt in two files using a keyword?

Tags: python, file, replace

I got three files:

1. list of keywords:

   ## file1

   ```
   NM_000015
   ```
2. tabulated data i need to insert :

   ## file2

   ```
   NM_000015   10  NAT2    N-acetyltransferase 2   9606
   ```
3. crude data where I need to insert :

   ## file3

   ```
   hsa-miR-153-5p  NM_000015   65.4643
   ```

I need to use keywords from file1 to find lines containing that keyword in file2 and replace that keyword in file3 with lines from file2.

result:

```
hsa-miR-153-5p  NM_000015   65.4643

hsa-miR-153-5p    NM_000015 10  NAT2    N-acetyltransferase 2   9606    65.4643
```

Comment: Could you please format your question a bit better? I'd propose an edit but I'm not sure how to edit this.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question appropriately.

Comment: i'd like to help but as the other have said, your question badly needs editing in order to be understood.

Comment: Please explain better this statement: "I need to use keywords from file1 to find lines containing that keyword in file2 and replace that keyword in file3 with lines from file2". For example, what happens if I found 10 lines in file2 with a keyword and there is only one line with the same keyword in file3?

Comment: Using a dictionary would seem a good approach, but I need an idea of volumes.  Approximately how many keywords are there in file1?  Is there only one set of tabulated data for each keyword in file 2?

Comment: sorry guys for bad formating ......  keywords are >100,000 and both files are about ~ 20 MB, using dictionary is really heavy on system. ISn't there any other way except Dict.

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel  file1 and file2 contains only single entries for each keyword, only file3 has multiple entries containing that keyword               I tried with itertools and replace() but no success

Comment: Just saw your update:  you can use a `shelve`.

Comment: Please note my edit suggestion that you use a set for the list of keywords.  A set will *probably* be faster than a list, but it depends on how critical memory becomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my Python 2 version:

```
# Construct list of keywords
# ** EDIT** this might be better as a set
# A list will use less memory, but a set is much faster lookup
keywords = [kw.rstrip() for kw in open('file1')]

# Construct dictionary of keywords
kvdict = {}

with open('file2') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        kw = line.split()[0]
        if kw in keywords:
            kvdict[kw] = line.rstrip()

with open('file3') as f3:
    for line in f3:
        kw = line.split()[1]
        if kw in kvdict:
            newline = line.replace(kw, kvdict[kw])
            print newline,       # or maybe write it to a file?
```

but it does depend on manageable numbers of keywords.  It also depends on every line in file3 having at least two fields.

For Python 3 change the final `print` statement to `print(newline, end='')`.

EDIT:  To avoid the memory overhead of the dictionary, replace

```
kvdict = {}
```

with:

```
import shelve
kvdict = shelve.open('keywords')
```

and near the end of the program put:

```
kvdict.close()
```

You might also like to remove the `keywords` file at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As others commented, your question lacks details to guide implementation. If I understood you correctly, something like this could work:

```
file1 = open("path_to_file1")
file2 = open("path_to_file2")
file3 = open("path_to_file3")

keywords = [ line[:-1] for line in file1 if line.strip() ]

translations = {
    line.partition('  ')[0]: line.partition('  ')[2][:-1]
    for line in file2
}

for line in file3 :
    if not line : continue
    for kwd in keywords :
        if kwd in line :
            print line.replace(kwd, translations[kwd])[:-1]
            break
    else :
        print line[:-1]
```

Implementation might differ according to your specification: what happens with lines in file3 that are not specified in file2? What happens with translations in file2 that are not given in file1? Can lines in file3 contain more than one keyword that should be replaced? etc. etc.

Comment: Honest, I didn't copy you!